# Input field not updating in the database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a laravel 5.2 project. I am referencing category_id from Posts.

My Post model looks like

```
class Post extends Model
{

    protected $fillable=['category_id '];


    public function category(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\category');
    }
}
```

Also, my form looks like

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category_id','Category:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, '1',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

</div>
```

My table data

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>

        <td>{{$post->category['name']}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

The Problem is, whenever I create a new post, the category name doesn't save in the database nor does it show on the front end.

My Post Schema table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();

});
```

Even when I `dd()` the input field for the category id on the post table, its empty. Can someone help me with this, it's making me go crazy. Thanks

I am using a resource contoller,heres my create request controller

```html
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user=Auth::user();
        $input = $request->all();
         Post::create($input);
        return redirect('admin/posts');
    }
```

Comment: where is your code involved with actually saving

Comment: protected $fillable=['category_id '] @lagbox

Comment: that is not the code involved with saving a record to the database. where is the controller

Comment: I have update my question with the controller

Comment: so where is the form input for 'name'  and how would it insert fields into 2 different tables?  how could it know 'name' is meant to be for a 'category'

Comment: the input field for category is select, in order words a drop down, the post table is meant to reference the category table via the category_id foreign key, there you can access other fields in the table.

Comment: if 'name' is for category you have to save it on the category model. adding attributes to post wont make eloquent save fields on the category table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error using this in my form.

```html
{!! Form::select('category_id', [''=>'choose Categories'] + $categories,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

and this on my table.

```html
<td>{{$post->category['name']}}</td>
```

Thanks all for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the fillable field only is the category_id try to add the category name field on your fillable like this.

```
//this are the fields that is fillable
protected $fillable=['category_id','name'];
```

With this the category name field will be able to catch and save data.

Comment: may I see your Posts Table structure?

Comment: you mean the model or migration?

Comment: the migration sir

Comment: okay, I think the issue is you forgot to add the category_name field. Your schema should look like.

Comment: why would the posts table have a category_name when it has a category_id that links to the categories table?

Answer (score 0):

Double check your fillable and input fields if they are the same.

your given concern you only show this one.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category_id','Category:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, '1',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}

</div>
```

how about the other fields. We expect you already had this on your form too.

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('input_name','Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::input('name',old('name'),['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => "input_name"]) !!}

</div>
```

In your store method it should look like this

```
  $new_post = new Post;
   $new_post->category_id = Input::get(‘category_id’);
$new_post->name = Input::get(‘name’);
$new_post->save();
```

Just in case you’re not using the fill method of $request

Comment: They are the same as you can see from my question

Comment: Can we look on your store method to validate your concern

Comment: I am not using any validation for now, no field is required.

Comment: @olasunkanmi i hope it helps you with this discussion. :)

Answer (score 0):

In continuation of my comment. Your migration should look like this.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('category_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('category_name')->nullable();

});
```

Your model,

```
class Post extends Model
{

    protected $fillable=['category_id','category_name'];

}
```

Form

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category_id','Category:') !!}
    {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, '1',['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    {!! Form::input('category_name',old('category_name'),['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => "input_name"]) !!}

</div>
```

and lastly your table data should look like this.

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$post->category_name}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your relationship's attributes, you should do:

```
 $post->comment->name;
```

And try to use 'fill()' when saving

```
 $post = new Post;
 $post->fill($request->all());
 $post->save();
```